# Windows 10 reboot issue

Tags: windows-10

My HP laptop is stuck on a reboot loop. Ctrl alt del has no effect.

F8 has no effect.

Pulling the battery has no effect.

Force restarting has no effect.

When I hit power button on bottom right of screen it says update and turn off or restart. It does not go into update, it will either shut down or restart.

Is there a way to get into the system without a recovery disk?

Comment: Press F8 continuously and fast while booting until the Windows logo appears.

Comment: Also try Esc and then F8. Also, hold the key *before* turning on, and keep pressed.

Answer (score -1):

Actually during startup should be some moment, when you can hit F8 and then enter to Safe mode. Probably, try several times, sometimes it's not easy.

Otherwise - no, you can't. What you can is:

- Use recovery disk, try to recover system
- Use live cd (or flash) to get access to your data or recover system
- Connect HDD to another PC to get access to your data